# Ruby case/when vs if/elsif

Tags: ruby

The `case`/`when` statements remind me of `try`/`catch` statements in Python, which are fairly expensive operations. Is this similar with the Ruby `case`/`when` statements? What advantages do they have, other than perhaps being more concise, to `if`/`elsif` Ruby statements? When would I use one over the other?

Comment: `case/when` is not same as `try/catch` and might behave differently from `if/else` if the `case equality` method (`===`) has been overriden

Comment: OK, but what is the advantage/disadvantage to case/when versus if/elsif? Why use one over the other and vice versa. Is one a more expensive operation in terms of memory and time, generally speaking, than the other?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `case` expression is not at all like a try/catch block. The Ruby equivalents to `try` and `catch` are `begin` and `rescue`.

In general, the case expression is used when you want to test one value for several conditions. For example:

```
case x
when String
  "You passed a string but X is supposed to be a number. What were you thinking?"
when 0
  "X is zero"
when 1..5
  "X is between 1 and 5"
else
  "X isn't a number we're interested in"
end
```

The case expression is orthogonal to the switch statement that exists in many other languages (e.g. C, Java, JavaScript), though Python doesn't include any such thing. The main difference with case is that it is an expression rather than a statement (so it yields a value) and it uses the `===` operator for equality, which allows us to express interesting things like "Is this value a String? Is it 0? Is it in the range 1..5?"

Comment: Thanks Chuck, I understand that case is used for checking multiple conditions but you can do the same thing with if/elsif. Other than looking nicer is there a reason to use case/when vs if/elsif especially regarding runtime and memory consumption.

Comment: @ChrisClouten: No. It's just a more readable way of expressing the idea. Ruby has a lot of syntactic niceties like this, like `unless` for `if not`.

Comment: Might be nice to also point out that, because of the `===` and how it works internally, when/case is slightly slower than if/else. Here's an explanation: http://www.daniellesucher.com/2013/07/23/ruby-case-versus-if/

Answer (score 3):

Ruby's `begin/rescue/end` is more similar to Python's `try/catch` (assuming Python's try/catch is similar to Javascript, Java, etc.).   In both of the above the code runs, catches errors and continues.

`case/when` is like C's `switch` and ignoring the `===` operator that bjhaid mentions operates very much like `if/elseif/end`.  Which you use is up to you, but there are some advantages to using `case` when the number of conditionals gets long.  No one likes `/if/elsif/elsif/elsif/elsif/elsif/end` :-)

Ruby has some other magical things involving that `===` operator that can make `case` nice, but I'll leave that to the documentation which explains it better than I can.